# Windows 8.1 Power User (Win + X) Menu not opening

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-key

When I:

- Press Win - X: Nothing happens
- Right click the [Windows 8.1 Start Button](http://prntscr.com/4pqa4a): The cursor moves upwards and to the right a bit, but nothing really *happens*.

I navigated to `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX` and all the folders

1. Group1
2. Group2
3. Group3

are empty... can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i uploaded mine (winx.rar) download it from (https://www.firedrive.com/file/EC8A3FB4B1D5916A)
i hope it work but something may delete it before you may change its permition to read only or system file so they will be more stable